# How do i Access this object item?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this response from a API:

```
Object { result: {…}, body: "{\n \"kind\": \"calendar#event\",\n \"etag\": \"\\\"123456789123\\\"\",\n \"id\": \"idIneedToAccess\",\n \"status\": \"confirmed\",\n \"htmlLink\": \"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=*********\",\n \"created\": \"2019-04-24T23:40:03.000Z\",\n \"updated\": \"2019-04-24T23:40:03.921Z\",\n \"summary\": \"Edelmiro\",\n \"description\": \"Agendado otro más\",\n \"creator\": {\n  \"email\": \"YYYYYYY@gmail.com\"\n },\n \"organizer\": {\n  \"email\": \"XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com\",\n  \"displayName\": \"Turnos\",\n  \"self\": true\n },\n \"start\": {\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-04-26T00:30:00-03:00\",\n  \"timeZone\": \"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires\"\n },\n \"end\": {\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-04-26T01:00:00-03:00\",\n  \"timeZone\": \"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires\"\n },\n \"iCalUID\": \"zzzzzzz@google.com\",\n \"sequence\": 0,\n \"reminders\": {\n  \"useDefault\": true\n }\n}\n", headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK" }
```

I have already tried:

```
var idTurno = response.body.id;
var idTurno = response.id;
var parseData = JSON.parse(response);
```

i need to get the id; thanks in advance!

Comment: console.log("Response", response);

is what whos that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there with `response.body.id` - the `body` is JSON, so use `JSON.parse` to parse it, then access the `id` you need:

```js
var response = { result: {/*stuff*/}, body: "{\n \"kind\": \"calendar#event\",\n \"etag\": \"\\\"123456789123\\\"\",\n \"id\": \"idIneedToAccess\",\n \"status\": \"confirmed\",\n \"htmlLink\": \"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=*********\",\n \"created\": \"2019-04-24T23:40:03.000Z\",\n \"updated\": \"2019-04-24T23:40:03.921Z\",\n \"summary\": \"Edelmiro\",\n \"description\": \"Agendado otro más\",\n \"creator\": {\n  \"email\": \"YYYYYYY@gmail.com\"\n },\n \"organizer\": {\n  \"email\": \"XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com\",\n  \"displayName\": \"Turnos\",\n  \"self\": true\n },\n \"start\": {\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-04-26T00:30:00-03:00\",\n  \"timeZone\": \"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires\"\n },\n \"end\": {\n  \"dateTime\": \"2019-04-26T01:00:00-03:00\",\n  \"timeZone\": \"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires\"\n },\n \"iCalUID\": \"zzzzzzz@google.com\",\n \"sequence\": 0,\n \"reminders\": {\n  \"useDefault\": true\n }\n}\n", headers: {/*more stuff*/}, status: 200, statusText: "OK" };
var idTurno = JSON.parse(response.body).id;
console.log(idTurno);
```